# Expand virtual hard disks on a Linux VM with the Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-disk

I am trying to extend a disk in my vm (azure). I used to do it like this:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc1
```

(sdc1 as an example)

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc
```

after typing `print`, I should see something like this:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdc1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: Unknown Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc1: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
    1      0.00B  107GB  107GB  ext4
```

I can't go any further because in my case after typing this command I see:

```
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 550GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
```

**As you can see, there are no partitions, so I can't use `resizepart` command.**

`lsblk -o NAME,HCTL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -i "sd"`

```
sda     1:0:1:0      16G 
└─sda1               16G /mnt
sdb     0:0:0:0      30G 
├─sdb1             29.9G /
├─sdb14               4M 
└─sdb15             106M /boot/efi
sdc     3:0:0:0     512G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see, there are no partitions, so I can't use resizepart
> command.

You Need to format the disk `sdc` to create partitions using either xfs or ext4 file system  & to procced further resize/[expand the disk partition & file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks#expand-a-disk-partition-and-filesystem).

**Cmdlets for disk format & diskpartition using XFS file system:**

```
sudo parted /dev/sdc --script mklabel gpt mkpart xfspart xfs 0% 100%
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdc1
sudo partprobe /dev/sdc1
```

Here we are formatting the disk using `XFS file system` & using the `partprobe`utility to make sure the kernel is aware of the new partition and filesystem.

Reference [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk#format-the-disk) to format the disk & also you can refer this [blog](https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-ext4-file-system-partition-in-linux/) on How to create a ext4 file system partition in Linux.

We have tested in our local environment creating a disk partition (to newly attached disk to the linux machine running with ubuntu 20.84 image)  & initializing the disk partition with xfs file system.

Below is the reference image  when we created a new disk & attached it to the virtual machine. When ran `lsblk` you see that disk is not mounted & it has no partitions.

[image]

[image]

In the above image, post running the above mentioned disk format & file partition cmdlets you can see a new partition with `sdc1` got created.